# Facebook page get user like status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I tried googling & checking stackoverflow for the possible solution but haven't found any yet, so would like to bring it up here again.

I have a Facebook page, page has multiple tabs, and one of the tab has a Facebook App (accessed only through the tab, redirect the http://apps.facebook.com/myapp to the page tab)

I have some content (say non-fan content) to be displayed to the user before he likes the page.but, I don't have any way to check if the user has liked the page unless he adds the app & fb documentation has stuff that can give me the required like FQL page_fan, url_like, api(/me/likes/FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID) but each one of this needs an accesstoken (which I cannot get before the user adds the app).

some of the posts on stackover flow says that is not possible without getting the user to add the app. but there are apps like static html, static iframe & others which provides this functionality, how ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will POST a `signed_request` to your server when the user opens the page tab.
This is what you get when you parse the `signed_request`:

```
{
    "algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256",
    "issued_at":1309468031,
    "page":{
        "id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "liked":true,"admin":true
    },
    "user":{"country":"fr","locale":"en_US","age":{"min":21}
}
```

The important part is "page.liked" where you see if the user likes the page.
No permissions and no app authorization is needed for this to work.

Search the web about parsing the `signed_request` in your favorite web programming language i.e. php.